# Can I add custom properties to PasswordCredential.Properties?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, passwordvault

In WinRT API there is Windows.Security.Credentials namespace which contains the [PasswordCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential.aspx) class.
Using it we can encrypt sensitive data like user names and passwords but the class itself has a property named "Properties" which looks to me like a handy container for other custom properties somehow related to the stored credential but I can't get it to work.
There is a "Read-only" access type for the "Properties" in the documentation but I thought that meant only that I can't change the reference to the container it points to.
My question is:

Is the "Properties" property of [PasswordCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential.aspx) useable for programmers?

Sorry for any errors in text, you can also correct my english in the answers, it is not my native language ;)

EDIT: This may be useful:

The "Add" method in the following code throws ArgumentException:

```
PasswordVault v = new PasswordVault();
PasswordCredential c = new PasswordCredential("TEST", "TEST", "TEST");
c.Properties.Add("Name", "testName");
v.Add(c);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the PasswordCredentials.Properties is an instance of [PasswordCredentialPropertyStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredentialpropertystore) which documentation describes every method as "...reserved for internal use and not intended to be used in your code".

That's why it is not useable for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

No it is a read only property, so you can't set it. It's designed so you can enumerate the properties of the object (not that the c# class properties, but the individual properties of a properties collection). The naming makes this confusing.

Comment: Well I know that PasswordCredential.Properties is only a container of key-value pairs. I wanted to use it's "Add" method to put in my own pairs, but it seems unusable. 

I thought the whole time that "Read-only" property means I can't set it, change the reference to the object it points to for example, but I can still use it's methods which modify the object like "Add" in my PasswordCredential.Properties collection.

Comment: You can if the underlying class allows it. I.e. if I had a readonly List<string> then I could add additional items to the existing list, but I couldn't put a new list in it's place, but it if it readonly IEnumerable<string> then I can't add anything to the colletion, or have it point to a new IEnumerable.

Comment: Well, let's say I understand ;)
The PasswordCredential.Properties returns an IPropertySet interface which extends IDictionary<string, object> and it has an Add method so in my opinion it should be usable.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is, you should be able to add things to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you actually try to add a property, you will get an **ArgumentException** - "_Property not found._"