# PasswordCredentials.Password is always empty in PasswordVault

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying following code to store username password in windows phone 8.1 PasswordVault it stores data but when I retrieve back password field is always empty.

```
  PasswordVault passwordVault = new PasswordVault();
  passwordVault.Add(new PasswordCredential("MyResouceKey", "username", "Password"));

 // Retrieval
 var credential = passwordVault.FindAllByResource("MyResourceKey");
  return credential.Password; /// it is always empty.
```

the password is always empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `credential.RetrievePassword()` before getting the `Password` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential.retrievepassword

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) one more question Do you know how to add properties in passwordcredentils?

Comment: Sorry, you can't add to the Properties collection, it's for internal use only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978958/can-i-add-custom-properties-to-passwordcredential-properties